# How to get access over cached images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How I access cached image files from loaded iframe web page with JS?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but something like `window.frames[1].document.images` may suit your needs.

Comment: Even if your English is not the best, this is no real question. What have you done and where have you failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it through **window.localStorage** with JS.

> The localStorage attribute provides persistent storage areas for domains

You can find more [info here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/).

Comment: Very interesting, how images are getting into `localStorage`?

Comment: @kirilloid, this is a part of the HTML5 API, it depends on browser's behaviour most of the time, but you can also set them manually thanks to JS. Example for some data, it is likely the same for an image: `sessionStorage.setItem("username", "Sidney");`

Comment: I'm trying to save an image with `localStorage.setItem("username", myImage);` but gets only `"[object HTMLImageElement]"` back. Me haz sad =(

Comment: You need to convert myImage into a `DataURL` element (.toDataURL("image/png")). You can check this out here ;)
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/

Comment: Cool. It's worth adding to the answer!

Comment: I want to access the images that are cached automaticaly from the system.http://imageshack.com/a/img22/3215/c1ib.png

Comment: You can load such images to canvas, but can not have per-pixel access later. Security policy.

Comment: What is this stupid security policy. I can save it, but can't access it with JS?